# How to create a cookie when making an axios request?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, axios

I'm building an app for personal use that gets data from Walmart and then displays clean data depending on what I want. I am having a problem. Every day, when I run my app. I have to insert a new cookie inside the headers because I guess it changes every day? Not sure but I was wondering if there is a way to create a cookie automatically or something like that.

I am using axios to make my get request. I already tried using npm cookie-parser, withCredentials: true, and a bunch of other things and none of them work. When I try it, the get request just fails. The only way it works is when I manually send a request, steal that cookie and put it inside my app.

Thank you.

Comment: You'd have to learn more about what is in the cookie to know anything more specifically.  Perhaps it's some sort of session ID that Walmart expires after some period of time.  If that's the case, this is entirely a server-side thing and you can't really do anything about it.  On the other hand, you can perhaps automate the process by which you're manually getting a cookie now so that you can get a new cookie in your app whenever you need one by just repeating the same process you're doing manually now, but in code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I thought so, and it does look like it is some sort of session ID, I learned that it expires after 24 hrs. I will try to automate the process by how I'm getting it at the moment. Thanks for the comment.